# TensorFlow shape error in feed_dict

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to adapt existing logreg example to my data and are getting the following error:

```
Epoch: 0001 cost=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tflin.py", line 64, in <module>
    print "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y:train_Y})), \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 315, in run
    return self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 506, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (60000, 6) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(6,)'
```

Source code can be found here: https://github.com/ilautar/tensorflow-test/blob/master/tflin.py

I'm sure it is obvious, any pointers?

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to feed a `60000 x 6` matrix into a `tf.placeholder()` that is defined to be a vector of length 6. This happens when you [try to feed the whole `train_X` matrix](https://github.com/ilautar/tensorflow-test/blob/master/tflin.py#L80) (as opposed to [feeding a single row](https://github.com/ilautar/tensorflow-test/blob/master/tflin.py#L76), which succeeds).

The best way to make this work is to do the following:

1. Define your placeholders (and model) in terms of batch inputs, which can have varying shape:

   ```
   # tf Graph Input
   X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
   Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
   ```
2. When feeding in a single example, extend it to be a `1 x 6` matrix using [`numpy.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

   ```
   # Fit all training data
   for epoch in range(training_epochs):
       for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
           sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x[numpy.newaxis, ...],
                                          Y: y[numpy.newaxis, ...]})
   ```

Comment: I had the same issue, yet when I use this fix i get the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: @ZachEisner It sounds like the values from which you're slicing are Python strings, rather than NumPy arrays. Feel free to post another question with a snippet of code showing where the probem occurs.

Comment: @mrry strange. I'll check and reformat accordingly. If it still doesn't work I'll definitely post a question. thanks!